# What is the most efficient way to increase my Herbalism level in MCMMO

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In the server I play, there is a jobs plugin in which you can get money. One of the included ways is from getting crops. The server also has the MCMMO plugin, and I want to get my herbalism skill level up so that I can get more money, and there are rewards for increasing your total MCMMO level on the server.

My level is currently at around 325, and one of the admins on the server had a WorldEdit-ed farm that he let me use. It is massive, and I have every single crop.

Up until now I have mainly been sprinting along rows of sugar cane that are 100 blocks long, but in between the growing periods I am having trouble getting experience. What is the most time-efficient way for me to increase my herbalism level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea with sugar cane. Each block broken is 30 exp, for a total of 60 if you break the middle after the top has grown. There's very little that comes close- cactus provides the same xp but is more difficult to harvest and everything else needs replanting. A few plants (flowers, mushrooms, etc.) provide more but can't really be farmed.

If you're spending too long waiting for the sugar cane to regrow, plant some more- you have a ridiculous amount of it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble gaining experience while waiting for crops to grow, simply plant more crops. Even if you plant them at the same time as you plant the other crops. This will allow for more time to be spent chopping down sugar can (which as studoku said, provides 30xp per cane chopped) and less time waiting for the sugar can to grow.

Answer (score 1):

Build 1 or more rows of sugar canes going as long as you like.  Then, make a minecart track along your farm.  Hold down the left mouse button as you ride along in a minecart, breaking the sugar canes as you ride along.  Doesn't work on servers with clear lag, as it removes minecarts.  This method will not hunger you, is faster than running along to break the sugar canes, and requires only one button.

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating, but a really easy way to level up Herbalism MCMMO while completely AFK.

Create a giant sugar cane farm. I built one that was 70x50 blocks. Now, get familiar with a program called AutoHotkey and run the script below after adjusting the timing to your farm size.

Put food in your far, right inventory slot and the script will start with you eating food, then it holds left for 12 seconds, up for a split second, right for 12 seconds, up for a split second, and then repeats for every row in the cane farm. When done, you eat again and wait 6 minutes. This repeats 30 times or for about 3hrs, giving you AFK Herbalism MCMMO.

```
;put food in the far right slot before running this script
;Press '9' on the keyboard to select the food, then right click to eat it
Send 9
send {click right down}
sleep 4000
send {click right up}

;Main Script: Repeat 30 times (about 3hrs)
loop, 30
{

;Teleport to the cane farm and wait 2 seconds
SendEvent /home cane{Enter}
sleep 2000

;Chop down all 22 rows of cane
;left 12sec, up 0.175sec, right 12sec, up 0.175 sec
loop, 11
{
send {click down}
Send {a down}
sleep 12000
send {a up}
send {w down}
sleep 175
send {w up}
send {d down}
sleep 12000
send {d up}
send {w down}
sleep 175
send {w up}
send {click up}
}

;eat food once you've chopped all the cane
Send 9
send {click right down}
sleep 4000
send {click right up}

;go back to the center of your cane farm and wait 6min for cane to grow
SendEvent /home canecenter{Enter}
sleep 2000
SendEvent /home canecenter{Enter}
sleep 360000
}
```